# When using external library from GITHUB Or NUGET what are some things to look for to make sure security risks do not exist?

Tags: javascript, security, github, nuget

When using packages installed to Visual Studio from NuGET for instances, what are some things I can look for within the javascript file(s) to make sure company or personal information isn't being captured and sent somewhere?

What keywords could I use to search other than http to make sure there are no extra calls transparently shipping out information?

I know that with these being open-source and all most likely a lot of eyes have been on it, but I want to take a look for myself.